# Copying a photo with ALAssetsLibrary's writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock: changes image orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I'm writing an app that takes an existing photo from the photo library, removes the GPS metadata, and writes out a copy of the photo with the new metadata.  The copied photos are displayed correctly in the Photos app on the phone and also in Preview.app in OS X, but Image Capture.app shows it with an incorrect orientation.  I can't figure out why this is happening.

Importing both the original and processed photos to the computer and opening them in Preview.app shows that all metadata is identical (except for the missing GPS dictionary).  With my test photo, Preview indicates both the original and the copy have "Orientation: 3 (Rotated 180)", and Preview does in fact show the correct orientation.  But Image Capture shows the copy as upside down, while the original displays correctly.  Obviously, I've missed something in my code, but what?  Here's the code that gets called from the UIImagePickerController's resultBlock:

```
// Make a copy of a photo, minus the GPS metadata tags.
- (void)copyPhoto:(ALAsset *)asset fromAssetsLibrary:(ALAssetsLibrary *)library
{
    // Get the image's current metadata
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    NSDictionary *metadata = [assetRepresentation metadata];
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableMetadata = [metadata mutableCopy];

    // Remove the GPS tags
    [mutableMetadata removeObjectForKey:@"{GPS}"];

    // Write out a copy
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage] metadata:mutableMetadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"We wrote out a picture!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you don't remove the `{GPS}` key?  Does it occur if you change the value for the key to something like the north pole instead of deleting it?

Comment: Great question.  It still occurs if I change no metadata at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason images are written to disk in the default orientation with the actual orientation specified in the metadata is so the camera hardware can take multiple photos in quick succession and save them near instantaneously without having the transform the image data each time.

When you programatically write a UIImage object to the iOS Photo library I believe it will actually transform the pixel data to the correct rotation according to the imageOrientation property of the UIImage object before writing it out. So when you call `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` it is transforming the image data to the correct rotation, but you are still supplying the original metadata with the now invalid image orientation value.

Try stripping the orientation metadata as well as the GPS information.

Comment: Are you sure about this? the image written to the photo library is a `CGImageRef` rather than a `UIImage`. As far as I know, these don't have extra orientation data at all.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but worth a try. It might be easier to deduce what's happening with an image rotated only 90 degrees instead of 180.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate from that angle.  Is there a way to get metadata from an existing photo and write out a copy without the system decompressing the JPEG into an image and then decompressing it?  Perhaps if it were just considered a stream of bits then it wouldn't adjust the orientation as you described.